# SSL connection error when connecting to RDS MySQL from Django

Tags: mysql, django, ssl, heroku, amazon-rds

I'm trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku with an RDS instance as the database backend. Everything is working until I try to encrypt the connection, then I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /path/
(2026, 'SSL connection error')
```

Here's the setup:

- Standard Django application
- MySQL RDS instance with security group allowing connections from all IP addresses
- MySQL user is setup to allow connections from any host
- Amazon's pem has been downloaded and is specified in Django settings

On Heroku:

```
DATABASE_URL: mysql2://username:password@instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/name_staging?sslca=path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem
```

In Django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {'ssl': {'ca': 'mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem'}}`
```

I've tried searching and have read a lot about setting this type of environment up in Rails, but the documentation about doing this with Django is light to non-existent.

Has anyone out there successfully deployed a similar setup or does anyone have thoughts on how to solve this error?

Update:

Connecting via cli works as well as connecting directly using MySQLdb in the python interpreter.

Comment: Googling around, a common error source appears to be mismatching CNs. Sadly, openssl's s_client doesn't work with mysql, otherwise you could easily debug this... can you connect via the mysql cli?

Comment: Yes, connecting via command line works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved:

The path to the pem file has to be absolute and you can't use python to attempt to build the absolute path.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
    'ssl': {'ca': '/app/project_name/rds/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem'}
}
```

Again, detecting the path like this does not work, the path must be hard coded:

```
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
    'ssl': {'ca': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'rds', 'mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem')}
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 1045 Error - what is this path relative to?  The main (root) directory?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be the full path.