# Access denied when connecting Django to RDS via SSL

Tags: django, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to connect Django to AWS Aurora server(RDS Aurora 5.6.10a) but I'm getting

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'admin'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
```

In Django settings.py, I've used the following settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': MYSQL_DATABASE,
        'USER': MYSQL_USER,
        'PASSWORD': MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': MYSQL_SERVER,
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'ssl': {
                'ca': '/Users/mac-user/workspace/project/settings/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also looked at similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711279/1238928) but didn't work

I've also tried to connect using `mysql-connector-python` and `mysql.connector.django` as database engine, and ensured that I'm setting the right configuration (setting `OPTIONS`'s `ssl_ca` and `ssl_verify_cert`) but I've also got a similar error:

```
 mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried to connect to the database using PHP and command line and it worked fine:

```
mysql -h '<host>' -u '<username>' -p'<password>' --ssl-ca='<SSL_certificate_absolute_path>'
```

Am I missing any configuration for Django?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to your problem, but apparently Aurora does not respond meaningfully (or correctly?) when MySQL client does not have ssl enabled (like MySQL command line and your PHP solution).

So my advice is to somehow force the MySQL client used by Django to use SSL connection, apparently it's not enabled/forced by default (the options you used might be insufficient).