# I am getting a 2026, SSL connection error when trying to connect my local django to an Amazon RDS MySQL database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to connect an Amazon RDS MySQL. It works fine when I run it on my terminal. I can connect with ease, but when I try to connect it using my Django app. It give me this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error:
>   SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')

My database config in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'llda_waterquality',
    'HOST': '<host_name>',
    'USER': '<rds_uname>',
    'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'PORT': '3306',

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing your `<ssl>.pem` file. 
You have to specify it in the `DATABASE OPTIONS` setting.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database
https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#functions-and-attributes

```py
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
    'ssl': {'ca': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'rds', 'mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem')}
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to specify the absolute path for the pem file.
Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709581/ssl-connection-error-when-connecting-to-rds-mysql-from-django) answer.