# SSL connection error when connecting to Amazon RDS mysql from python mysql connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-rds

I am trying to use `mysql.connector` in Python 3.7 to connect to an Amazon RDS MySQL database I created following this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/). In python if I try

```
mysql.connector.connect(host="hostname.rds.amazonaws.com",
                        user="username", passwd="password", 
                        database="databasename")
```

I get the following error:

```
MySQLInterfaceError: SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed
```

What is the error referring to? If I connect with the same credentials from the command line using `mysql` or mysql workbench I have no problems.

**Update:**

It must have been an issue with the anaconda environment I was using. I've since used pip3 to install mysql-connector and it works correctly.

Comment: AWS RDS switched from yaSSL to openssl right around where I noticed the problem (mysql 5.6.39) which I think was auto-updated since it's a minor version bump; I suspect it's a problem with the switch that may have been smoothed over by a different version of openssl when you used pip. [aws link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport)

Comment: Right thanks, could be. I've since removed anaconda so can't check whether the problem persists there.

Comment: Heh, that’s why I added a comment instead of an answer. ;) My solution was just to switch databases since this hasn’t hit production yet. I did also notice that conda recently bumped OpenSSL and tons of packages on conda-forge had to be rebuilt as well so it certainly seems like something there broke.

Answer (score 0):

It failed to set a Diffie-Hellman parameter in your SSL context, probably due to a missing .pem file. Please see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#s-connecting-to-the-database) and [SSL connection error when connecting to RDS MySQL from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709581/ssl-connection-error-when-connecting-to-rds-mysql-from-django#answer-20711279), which suggests adding an option like

```
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {
    'ssl': {'ca': '/app/project_name/rds/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the error code. I don't really understand why this is coming up though, because I'm not trying to connect with ssl.